.NET Maui database issues
I am building an app in .net maui and have been tackling issues with my database forever, i am now using Sqlite but can't see the database, I have found the AppDataDirectory using Android Emulator but it's not updating the db file in my dbbrowser
Is there a way I can have my file saved to my root directory of my app, I know it's a security risk but I don't see another way.  I've read about using a seperate web api, but have not seen any code already written to demonstrate how you would connect the two. Also please comment on how I did my user login, I have two tables "User" and "Habit" as it's a habit tracker app and the tables are connected and everything works fine but is that really the best way? I apologize as I'm a beginner in .Net maui and am trying to not only do this project well but also improve my code style so any suggestions will be very well received.
Thank you again!
This is how I did my Constants file

using System;
using System.IO;  // Ensure you include the System.IO namespace for path operations

namespace App.Data
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        // Name of the database file
        public const string DatabaseFilename = "database.db3";

        // Configuration flags for SQLite connection
        public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags =
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | // open the database in read/write mode
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create |    // create the database if it doesn't exist
            SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache; // enable multi-threaded database access

        // Full path to the database file
        public static string DatabasePath =>
            Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, DatabaseFilename); // Corrected to use FileSystem.AppDataDirectory properly
    }
}



Please read [ask] before posting.  It helps to focus on a single specific problem, not several.  The app bundle is read-only, you can't write to any files in it.  You need to use adb to extract the db file from your device or emulator to your desktop in order to read it with a tool like DB Browser.  The tool can't directly access files in the Android filesystem.

You can try to put the data file into the resources of the MAUI project and read it through code.
